# Show different outputs when dropdownlist selection changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `ViewModel` with a `List<Mouse>`. In my `view`, binded with that `viewmodel`, I have a `dropdownlist` with mouse ids. When the user selects an item from the list, I have to change the information displayed on the page in a lot of textboxes (showing mouse information).
How can I do this?(Using controller/razor/..?)

I've tried with

```
@Html.DropDownList(mouseList, new { AutoPostBack = "true",OnSelectedIndexChanged="GarantiDropDown_Change" })
```

and inserting method in controller but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not such things as `autoPostBack` or `onSelectedItemChanged` events in **asp.net mvc** . these belong to **asp.net WebForms** . in order to do what you want , you should use **javascript** .

something like this :

```
@Html.DropDownList(mouseList, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

and in the `controller` add an `action` to recieve the `form` data.

check these questions [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730800/c-sharp-how-to-set-the-autopostback-property-when-using-asp-net-mvc) , [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510821/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-on-change-to-cause-postback-without-javascript) , [+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189585/asp-net-mvc-autopostback-drop-down-not-working):